# Wrong if statement jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

So I have a counter which counts down to 0 so when it hits 0 I want it to do a pdo update. The problem is that the `if` statement lets the update happen on each page refresh and does not wait for the count to hit 0.
I have looked at the code and can not see where I am going wrong.

```
<?php   $timer = '20'; ?>
window.onload = function(){

(function(){
  var counter = <?php echo $timer ; ?>;

  setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if (counter >= 0) {
      span = document.getElementById("count");
      span.innerHTML = counter;
    }
    // Display 'counter' wherever you want to display it.
    if (counter === 0) {


        document.getElementById( "response" ).innerHTML = "<div style=\"float: right; display: inline-block; margin: 6px;\"><div class=\"skip_btn\">
<?php 
    $sqll = "UPDATE users SET coins=coins+? WHERE username=?";
    $q = $db->prepare($sqll);
    $q->execute(array('1',$_SESSION['username']));
    $sqll2 = "UPDATE websites SET clicks_left=clicks_left-? WHERE id=?";
    $q2 = $db->prepare($sqll2);
    $q2->execute(array('1',$row['id']));
?>
</div></div><div style=\"clear:both;\"></div>";
    }

  }, 1000);

})();

}
```

I have just fixed it buy using a parser

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>          
<script type="text/javascript">

// Check if the page has loaded completely                                         
$(document).ready( function() { 
    setTimeout( function() { 
        $('#some_id').load('parser.php'); 
    }, 10000); 
}); 
</script>
```

Thanks for the warm welcome tot he site tho.

Comment: Sorry misspelled . I mean statement

Comment: Try calling $jQuery->doMagicTrick(); ... but seriously, this is not how PHP works

Comment: The PHP statements will execute at the time the page is rendered. They won't be called again. You need to implement some sort of AJAX call to a server-side script that will do the update for you.

Comment: The counter is not set to 0 tho so it chouldn't call the php i don't think.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var counter = 20;
    setInterval(function() {
        if( counter == 0 ) {
            $.post("url/to/php");
        }
        else {
            $("#div_for_showing_counter").html(counter);
            counter--;
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

This way you separate client side from server side. You can do whatever you want in the php file. If you need a callback or you need to pass data to the php file then simply modify the $.post to something like this:

```
$.post("url/to/php", { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" }, function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```